# Populate Dropdown from another Table/View

Tags: django, django-forms, dropdown, modelform

I have a *site* model which is connected to the *municipality* where the site is located. Using this municipality in a dropdown field in the create form leads to quite long loading times. The reason is the large amount of municipalities in the database but also that the administrative units are linked to each other which seems to lead to cascading queries to populate the dropdown field.

Is there a way to speed this up? I thought about making a materialized view and use it to populate the dropdown field but that would lead to a value error because the value from the dropdown must be an instance of the linked model as far as I know. Is there maybe another way to make the form load faster? Or is the materialized view the way to go and I am just getting something wrong?

```
class site(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    site_notes = models.CharField(max_length=2500, blank=True, null=True)
    municipality = models.ForeignKey('local_administrative_unit', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)

class administrative_level_5(models.Model):
    al5_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    al5_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {}'.format(self.al5_id, self.al5_name)


class administrative_level_4(models.Model):
    al4_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    al4_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    adm_level_5 = models.ForeignKey('administrative_level_5', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {} ({})'.format(self.al4_id, self.al4_name, self.adm_level_5.al5_name)


class administrative_level_3(models.Model):
    al3_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    al3_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    adm_level_4 = models.ForeignKey('administrative_level_4', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

def __str__(self):
  return '{}, {} ({})'.format(self.al3_id, self.al3_name, self.adm_level_4.al4_name)
    
class administrative_level_2(models.Model):
    al2_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    al2_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    adm_level_3 = models.ForeignKey('administrative_level_3',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {} ({})'.format(self.al2_id, self.al2_name, self.adm_level_3.al3_name)

class local_administrative_unit(models.Model):
    lau_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lau_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    adm_level_2 = models.ForeignKey('administrative_level_2', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {} ({})'.format(self.lau_id, self.lau_name, self.adm_level_2.al2_name)
```

Form looks like this

```
class NewSiteForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.site
        fields = (
            'site_name', 
            'site_notes', 
            'municipality'
        )
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your form and the `__str__` methods of your models? By default the `__str__` method is used to generate the labels in the dropdown, sounds like you have a `__str__` method that accesses related models?

Comment: I will post the code later when I am back home. I think the Str methods access other models but on one hand it is quite useful to incorporate higher hierarchy levels to make Identification of the right municipality easier on the other hand there are about 20k municipalities which is quite a bit to fetch anyway i think...

Comment: I removed the references in the str methods and it is **a lot** faster now, thank you for the advice! However, for reasons of clarity, I would also like to display the higher-level administrative units in this dropdown. For example, *"lau_name, administrative_level_2 (administrative_level_3)"* or *"Greenwich, Greater London (England)"* to give some arbitrary example. what is the best way to do this without producing the problem just solved again?